# Symfony2: custom HTML inside label

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is there a way with Symfony 2 forms to add HTML inside a label?

I want:

```
<label for="myfield"><span class="photo">My label</span></label>
```

How can I write it?
None of these ideas work properly as expected:

```
<span class="photo">{{ form_label(form.myfield) }}</span>
```

Or

```
{{ form_label(form.myfield, '<span class="photo">'~myfield~'</span>') }}
```

Thanks for your help,
A

Comment: First idea doesn't work? Why? I mean, it should :)

Comment: Because the <label> is inside the <span>... I want the contrary.

Comment: The " you have in your second example (instead of ') is just a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes it was... thanks, I just edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look to [Symfony2 Form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) documentation, especially to the "[Adding a "Required" Asterisk to Field Labels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels)" section.

I am not sure this is the best way to go, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it like this:

```
enter code here

{{ form_label(form.myfield,'Name of the label') }}
{{ form_errors(form.myfield)}}
{{ form_widget(form.myfield),{attr:{'class':'photo span'}}) }}
```